# Vesta / Cloudflare DNS/ Can't connect to mail server with outlook client

Tags: email, outlook, dns, vesta

I started to use Cloudflare, but I got some problems with mail management.
**I can receive and send emails through Vesta Roundcube webmail.** But my outlook client stopped working. **I can't add my email to any email client such as Apple Mail or Outlook.** I think it does not receive a message from the mail server. I am stuck, I don't know where to look next.

This is my config on Cloudflare. And it seems fine. My web and email is on a different webserver.
Any idea of what should be changed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. Change your mail A record from "Proxied" to Dns only.

[image]